# Spring boot JPA many to many query | find all courses courses which are attended students

Tags: java, spring, jpa, many-to-many

For example, we have students S1, S2, S3, S4 and courses C1, C2 and C3.

Students S1, S2 attent C1

Students S1, S2, S3 attend C2.

Find all courses, in which S1 and S2 attend together

(expected answer C1 and C2)

Would also be grateful if answer can be shown how to implement in Spring JPA / CRUD repository.

Entities:

```
class Course {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //debugging purpouses
    @JoinTable(name = "course_students",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"))
    Set<Student> students;
}

class Student {
    @Id
    String id;
    String firstName;
    String middleName;
    String lastName;
    String phoneNumber;
    String email;
    String avatar;
    int age;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "students")
    Set<Course> courses;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your entity mapping?

Comment: @talex Just added them in the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query(Select c from Course c group by c having :student_lst in array_arg(c.student))
List<Course> findCoursesByStudents(@param("student_lst") List<Student> student_lst);
```

You can use above query for your task.In this query first students group by the courses they attend.After get grouped filter out the courses where the student_lst is subset of all student list grouped by course.

Answer (score 1):

Use MEMBER OF :

```
select c from Courses c where :student1 member of c.students and :student2 member of c.students
```

Answer (score 1):

To get students enrolled in course, this goes something like in queries as:

```
@Query("select student from Student student join student.courses course
where course.name in :givenCourses")
List<Student> getStudentsByCourses(
 @Param("givenCourses") List<String> givenCourses )
```

same as vice versa to find specific course attended by students

```
@Query("select course from Course course join course.students student
where student.firstName in :enrolledStudentList")
List<Course> getCoursesAttendedByStudents(
 @Param("enrolledStudentList") List<String> enrolledStudentList )
```